# Language of all the binary words that not contains continuum of more then $3$ zeros

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

I need to write a regular expertion for the language of all the binary words that not contains continuum of more then $3$ zeros, for example $0011110100\in L,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,11000001100\notin L $

**My try:**

$[(0+1)^*+(00+1^*)^*+(000+1^*)]^*$

> My attempt is correct?

Comment: Do you mean string contatenation with $+$ or a choice of options? If it is the latter then $(0+1)^*$ already matches all binary strings.

Comment: @Jorik "$+$" same like "or"

Comment: so $[1^*+(00+1^*)^*+(000+1^*)]^*$ ?

Comment: Still doesn't quite work since $(00 +1^*)^*$ matches $0000$. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $\varepsilon$ for the empty string and if $s$ is some string then write $s^+$ for repeating $s$ one or more times, i.e. $s^+ = ss^*$.

If $s\in L$ then either $s$ contains no ones or $s$ is of the form $s=0^*t0^*$ where $t$ is a string that begins and ends with a one and contains no 3 zeroes in a row. The following regular expression matches all strings that begin and end with a $1$ and do not contain $3$ zeroes in a row:
$$E=1^+\left(0(1^+) + 00(1^+)\right)^*$$
This expression says that the string must start with at least one 1 and then it can have 1 or 2 zeroes followed by more ones any number of times.

The full answer would then be
$$(\varepsilon + 0 + 00) + (\varepsilon + 0 + 00 )E(\varepsilon + 0 + 00)$$
Where $E$ is the expression defined above.

Edit: I later realized an easier, or at the very least shorter way.
$$\left((\varepsilon+0+00)1\right)^*(\varepsilon+0+00)$$